# Why do my BT headphones default to HSP/HFP upon connection >80% of the time?

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones, bluez

I'm using Ubuntu 19.10 on a Dell XPS 13 9380. I've looked everywhere, even gone so far as digging through the Bluez source online to find the exact line of code or configuration that causes this infuriating behaviour: not only why A2DP is not a far more reasonable default but more importantly, why such a common usecase (i.e. the choice of default BT profile upon connection) is not something users can configure/select, amidst all the existing options in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf, most of which users probably have no need to change anyways. I've found clues that something resembling this config once existed but has since been removed for some reason; Bluez no longer recognizes those settings as I can see in my system logs.

It would be only slightly better if using PulseAudio/Blueman to select the profile manually every time, was good enough. But that doesn't always work, sometimes it just seems to get hung and disconnects from the headset in the process, streaming audio through my PC speakers instead. Then I need to turn off the headphones and turn them back on and hope it works this time. I'd consider the possibility that this is somehow an issue with my headphones except my Android has never had this issue even once, so I'm more inclined to believe my PC's the one constantly dropping the ball.

Rant done, has anyone faces this issue before and perhaps knows something that worked for them? Or if the recent 20.04 release somehow holds some magical cure for this?

**Update**: Upgrading to 20.04 (which includes Bluez 5.53) changed nothing. The headphones still default to HSP/HFP. Have pretty much resigned myself to switching profiles manually everytime with BlueMan, at this point. If anyone finds a real solution later, they're of course still free to provide an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue is caused by Bluez contending with the headset, for the right to connect A2DP first. Some headsets don't handle such crossovers well -- in this case, the confusion manifests as the headset taking several seconds to respond to AVDTP commands.

The result is that, when PulseAudio needs to urgently route audio, it *seems* it notices A2DP isn't connected yet and just takes the closest alternative, being HFP/SCO.

On 21.10 Impish Indri, the result is even worse, some Bluez A2DP timeout kicks in because of the headset's delayed responses, and A2DP is disconnected entirely, followed shortly by the other profiles.

A ticket's been raised here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1941977, in case anyone else has the same issue and would like to pile on. But I won't be marking this as Answered yet, until someone from the Bluez team confirms the analysis there, merges the proposed changes and I'm able to confirm the result *does* fix the issue with my headset.

Comment: And another here: https://github.com/bluez/bluez/issues/205